# Doubts about Macros in C

Tags: c, macros

```
#define MHZ *1000000l
#define MSEC /1000l
```

This is the function defination

```
unsigned int SysTick_Config(unsigned int ticks)
{
  if (ticks > SysTick_LOAD_RELOAD_Msk) 
  return (1);   // Reload value impossible 

  STRELOAD = (ticks & SysTick_LOAD_RELOAD_Msk) - 1; // set reload register 

  return (0);  // Function successful 
}
```

The Function is called as mentioned below

```
 SysTick_Config(96MHZ * 2.5MSEC);
```

My doubt is about the macro used.Does writing 96MHZ mean it gets replaced by (96 * 1000000l) ? Does 96 get multiplied by 1000000 ? 
 Also, what does /1000l in #define MSEC /1000l mean? why is the / used.

I am using IAR embedded workbench

Comment: Edit your question to include `C` tag; and could you please tell us how did you compile your code; what compiler you are using?for `gcc` I have got `error: invalid suffix "MHZ" on integer constant`. but I works if I modified it to `SysTick_Config(96 MHZ * 2.5 MSEC);`

Comment: Probably it is not '1' at the end, but letter 'l', long suffix for integral constants.

Comment: thank you..Its ' l ' and not 1..My compiler is showing l and 1 as same...so,may be i got confused

Comment: @tapanchawda why don't you compile it and see what happends?

Comment: I have compiled it..No errors

Comment: In case of doubt, first try it.... Another point: such suffixes defined as macros are dangerous,  as `1 + 1 MHZ` expands to `1 + 1*1000000` The usual notation of suffixes (applying to the whole expression)  conflicts with what C does of them.

Comment: If the compiler actually compiles that, it's got a serious bug, and it's a clbuttic mistake just waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

When using macros next to a number like this, there needs to be whitespace between the number and the macro. You should be seeing a compiler error in this case.

The `/1000l` is simply division by 1000.

Comment: sounds more like a comment than an answer

Comment: Well, I was answering what used to be the question in the OP, but the OP has been changed since. *shrug*

Comment: i know the feeling, moving target

Comment: I've uncomment-ified it, unless the OP changes yet again. :)

Comment: judging from what we have seen so far, it seems highly possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add whitespace between the literals and the macros, otherwise the compiler will consider them to be invalid integral and float constants:

```
SysTick_Config(96 MHZ * 2.5 MSEC);
```

After preprocessing, that line will be expanded to

```
SysTick_Config(96 *1000000l * 2.5 /1000l); // trailing l makes the type
                                           // of the constant a long
                                           // int instead of a regular int
```

Note that this style of programming will cause problems if you write something like

```
SysTick_Config(a + b MHZ * c - d MSEC);
```

you will need to make sure you explicitly group things together, like

```
SysTick_Config((a+b) MHZ * (c-d) MSEC);
```

I know some people like to write code this way, thinking it's self-documenting.  I think it's a mistake, and not only because it can lead to precedence issues.

A safer method is to use a *function-like* macro that takes an argument:

```
/**
 * When creating macros for arithmetic expressions, it's a good
 * idea to use parentheses around each macro argument and the
 * entire macro expansion itself; this way you can avoid
 * precedence issues if you pass an expression like a+b to
 * the macro.   
 */
#define TO_MHZ(x)  ((x) * 1000000L) // use uppercase L to avoid confusion
#define TO_MSEC(x) ((x) / 1000L )   // with the digit 1
```

and use them as

```
SysTick_Config( TO_MHZ(96) * TO_MSEC(2.5) );
```

which expands to

```
SysTick_Config( ((96) * 1000000L) * ((2.5) / 1000L) )
```

or

```
SysTick_Config( TO_MHZ(a+b) * TO_MSEC(c-d) );
```

which expands to

```
SysTick_Config( ((a+b) * 1000000L) * ((c-d) / 1000L) );
```

This way there's no confusion, and you avoid any precedence issues.